# How to perform Django email threading?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, email, asynchronous

Can someone please share how I can do threading to send an email on a shared hosting service for my Django app? I have tried python threading which works perfectly on localhost but doesn't send an email on cloud hosting.

Moreover, I tried looking for celery broker but couldn't find anything on the shared hosting. Can someone suggest how to send an email on the Django app in the background so that the user doesn't have to wait?

N.B: Changing the hosting service is not an option. Currently using Namecheap shared hosting.

Comment: Why celery is not an option?

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the cPanel to run the celery app. Can you share some resource where it can be done on the shared hosting?

Comment: what stopping you from adding celery or any other background task running library to your django project? Those library run on separate threads so it should be perfect for this

Comment: If you cant spin a celery, you can call an AWS lambda function that will do it